# How to compile PHP with OpenSSL on OS X 10.9?

Tags: php, openssl, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to compile PHP 5.6.10 from the source, and I encountered the following problem:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC", referenced from:
      _zif_openssl_pbkdf2 in openssl.o
  "_TLSv1_1_client_method", referenced from:
      _php_openssl_setup_crypto in xp_ssl.o
  "_TLSv1_1_server_method", referenced from:
      _php_openssl_setup_crypto in xp_ssl.o
  "_TLSv1_2_client_method", referenced from:
      _php_openssl_setup_crypto in xp_ssl.o
  "_TLSv1_2_server_method", referenced from:
      _php_openssl_setup_crypto in xp_ssl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1
```

OpenSSL is installed via Brew. In PHP included like `--with-openssl=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2c`

P.S.
Before tried to use just `/usr` for OpenSSL but got the same error.

Comment: Could you give you plateform details and compiler informations ?

Comment: @cyrbil what exactly do you need?

Comment: Your OS version `uname -smorv` and your compiler `gcc --version` (assuming you use gcc ...)

Comment: @cyrbil here is your options https://www.dropbox.com/s/ap129bv74les772/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202015-06-24%2015.58.15.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you accept @Bob answer please as it is correct? thank you

Answer (score 10):

The Makefile has a line with `EXTRA_LIBS`, something like:

```
EXTRA_LIBS = -lresolv -lmcrypt -lltdl -liconv-lm -lxml2 -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto
```

Remove all occurrences of `-lssl` and `-lcrypto` and add the full path to `libssl.dylib` and `libcrypto.dylib` *(brew links openssl to /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/)*

```
EXTRA_LIBS = -lresolv -lmcrypt /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib -lltdl -liconv-lm -lxml2 -lcurl
```

Comment: Also for El Capitan 10.11.4 with PHP 7.0.5 + OpenSSL 1.0.2g, manual installation (no brew, no ports).

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on Bob Fanger's answer (which worked perfectly for me on os x 10.11.3), here's a little script you can run from within the build directory that makes the Makefile changes:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
if (true != copy('Makefile', 'Makefile.sav'))
    die("** cannot copy 'Makefile' to 'Makefile.sav'\n");
$lines = file('Makefile');
if (false == $lines)
    die("** connot read 'Makefile'\n");
$output = fopen('Makefile', 'wb');
if (false == $output)
    die("** unable to open 'Makefile'\n");
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^EXTRA_LIBS\s+=\s+/', $line)) {
        $line = preg_replace('/^EXTRA_LIBS\s+=\s+/', 'EXTRA_LIBS = /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib', $line);
        $line = preg_replace(['/-lssl/', '/-lcrypto/'], [], $line);
    }
    if (false === fwrite($output, $line))
        die("** writing line to 'Makefile' failed\n");
}
fclose($output);
echo "Success - your Makefile is set for ssl\n";
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

if you're using phpbrew on OSX El Capitan you need to provide the full path of your openssl:

`phpbrew install php-7.0.4 +openssl=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/[YOUR OPEN SSL VERSION]`